# Python BeautifulSoup Parsing Not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have mainly used python for data anlaysis and new to scraping. I am trying to learn the BeautifulSoup package. I am having problems to make the following code work.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('http://pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html')
bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html)
name_list = bsobj.findAll('span',{'class':'green'})
```

I am getting an empty list.

It's clear that the problem comes from the 4th line. I am not sure why. Everything is standard here. I don't know what went wrong.

```
bsobj.prettify()
```

Returns ''

But when I do html.read(), I can see all the html code fine.
The problem is not solved by the answers below. The problem clearly comes from line4. It doesn't matter if I use bsobj.findAll(), or bsobj.find_all(). They are equilvalent and as I mentioned, the bsobj.prettify() returns ''.

Comment: add `print(bsobj.prettify())` and post output

Comment: If `bsobj` is `None` print `html`.

Comment: `bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')`

Answer (score 0):

I think that line should be `bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())`

Comment: 'html.parser' is actually not a good parser. `'lxml'` is better, and it is the default choice, anyway.

Comment: @DYZ I was about to add it! :) I myself use more `lxml` - see my GitHub :)

Comment: @YanSong is your problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The findall is wrong...

```
bsobj.find_all('span',{'class':'green'})
```

It returns

```
[<span class="green">Anna
 Pavlovna Scherer</span>, <span class="green">Empress Marya
 Fedorovna</span>, <span class="green">Prince Vasili Kuragin</span>, <span class="green">Anna Pavlovna</span>, <span class="green">St. Petersburg</span>, <span class="green">the prince</span>, <span class="green">Anna Pavlovna</span>, <span class="green">Anna Pavlovna</span>, <span class="green">the prince</span>, <span class="green">the prince</span>, <span class="green">the prince</span>, <span class="green">Prince Vasili</span>, <span class="green">Anna Pavlovna</span>, <span class="green">Anna Pavlovna</span>, <span class="green">the prince</span>, <span class="green">Wintzingerode</span>, <span class="green">King of Prussia</span>, <span class="green">le Vicomte de Mortemart</span>, <span class="green">Montmorencys</span>, <span class="green">Rohans</span>, <span class="green">Abbe Morio</span>, <span class="green">the Emperor</span>, <span class="green">the prince</span>, <span class="green">Prince Vasili</span>, <span class="green">Dowager Empress Marya Fedorovna</span>, <span class="green">the baron</span>, <span class="green">Anna Pavlovna</span>, <span class="green">the Empress</span>, <span class="green">the Empress</span>, <span class="green">Anna Pavlovna's</span>, <span class="green">Her Majesty</span>, <span class="green">Baron
 Funke</span>, <span class="green">The prince</span>, <span class="green">Anna
 Pavlovna</span>, <span class="green">the Empress</span>, <span class="green">The prince</span>, <span class="green">Anatole</span>, <span class="green">the prince</span>, <span class="green">The prince</span>, <span class="green">Anna
 Pavlovna</span>, <span class="green">Anna Pavlovna</span>]
```